# How can I run multi-update in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, sql-update

I want to run about 100.000 rows update in Access (see below the template).

```
update Entries set GL = '345' where GL = '398965';
update Entries set GL = '546' where GL = '522954';
update Entries set GL = '576' where GL = '556395';
update Entries set GL = '963' where GL = '944485';
update Entries set GL = '334' where GL = '347563';
update Entries set GL = '997' where GL = '978964';
```

When a run the script appear the following error message.

> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

The official Microsoft answer for the problem was not so helpful:

> You entered data after using a semicolon (;) in the SQL statement. For example, "SELECT * FROM table1; garbage" will generate this error. To prevent this error, remove any characters following the semicolon (;).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Run the updates one at a time.

Comment: I need to run about 100.000 rows.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should adjust the way you're updating rows. You aren't generating this query by hand, so you should adjust the program generating the query. In Access, the max length of a query is about 65.000 characters, not enough to write an update statement for 100.000 rows. Please ask about the actual problem, not your solution that can never work.

Comment: And why doesn't work this code with 500 rows?

Comment: What is the criteria/logic for setting the new value? Does GL have to be of a certain length/contain a certain character for it to be changed to three characters?

Comment: @blackcornail probably because you're executing it as a single query. Access doesn't support running multiple statements at once, if you're executing this as a single statement it won't work.

Comment: @AceAmr I have a table about GL Entries, and I have got a list of GL Numbers what I have to modify (so there isn't logic or criteria just a mapping table). I created the update script with a dynamic excel code.

Comment: If you have the list in Excel, just use that in a query. Access can easily refer to Excel files in queries

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table (UpdateTable) with old value (OldValue) and new value (NewValue), then update via join

```
Update T
set T.GL = X.NewValue
from Entries T
inner join UpdateTable X
on X.OldValue = T.GL
```

or in Access:

```
UPDATE Entries 
INNER JOIN (UpdateTable
ON Entries.GL = UpdateTable.OldValue)
SET Entries.GL = UpdateTable.NewValue
```

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Good point, it's been a while since I've Access'ed